# Why STL algorithms are not overloaded for std::tuple?

Tags: c++, tuples, std-pair, stl-algorithm, stdtuple

I was wondering why there is no overload for some STL algorithms in order to make them usable with tuples. By some, I mean those which do not reorder elements. A good example might be `std::for_each`.

Is there a language limitation, such as maybe the fact the is not possible to mix compile-time evaluation and run-time evaluation? Let me clarify this last sentence:

I know that the iteration itself would need to become a compile-time iteration, compile time iterators then have to be defined in order to use the compile-time `std::get<>` to fetch values. After that, it should be possible to apply a templated lambda to every eterogeneous type in a tuple, but the value of that type is then runtime evalutated.

I think it should be possible, even if I personally would not know where to start. I saw implementations that do not look like `std::for_each` at all to achieve the same result. Why is so?

(NOTE: by 'tuple' I mean both `std::pair` and `std::tuple`)

Comment: It would be a bit difficult considering that both `std::pair` and `std::tuple` allow you to store completely different (heterogeneous) types. How exactly would you apply any of the standard library algorithms when the stored types have nothing in common?

Comment: Tuples and pairs are *mixtures* of different data types. How would you write a generic function when each element is a different type?

Comment: shouldn't it be possible with templated lambda, to pass a function that applies to any data type? For example:
`[](const auto& value){ std::cout << value; }`

Comment: `auto` is not "match any type to me". `auto` is a type deduced by compiler at compile-time. And it's exactly one type.

Comment: and shouldn't this then be expanded to many different functor types?

Comment: Because in this case they should be compile time. C++ 20 should have compile time versions.

Comment: A large limitation is you can't pass *multiple overloads* of a given function name as a parameter. You can't have a function template parameter either.

Comment: @Caleth As far as I remember, but I might be wrong, templated template parameter should be possible.

Comment: Hmm, I think I was confused by the restriction (pre C++17) that you had to spell it `template<template<...> class>`. I guess you can pass a template function as a parameter

Answer (score 3):

STL algorithm uses iterators, which is incompatible with `std::tuple`.

`std::tuple` comes with its own set of functions, so your `for_each` might be done with `std::apply`:

```
std::apply([](const auto&... args)
          {
              ((std::cout << args << std::endl), ...); // C++17 Fold expression
          }, t);
```

Comment: While this is very true for `std::for_each`, all the other STL algorithms that do not modify the data needs to be rewritten by hand. Why do you state that iterators are incompatible with `std::tuple`? The only issue I see is that iterator changes its type when you call its `operator++`, which is no big deal I guess as you might just store it in a different auto-typed variable, and call recursively `std::for_each` using the new variable as "begin" parameter.

Comment: *"The only issue I see is that iterator changes its type when you call its operator++"* so it would not be a regular iterator, so current algorithm would have to be rewritten. Moreover, most algorithms seems "un-adapted" to `tuple`, `std::sort` on tuple, `std::min_element` which would literally compare orange with apple... if your tuple is homogeneous, then convert it to (reference) array might be a viable solution.

Comment: If the definition of iterator might need to be expanded it does not mean that the iterator concept is incompatible with `std::tuple` per-se. So the question is still: is there any language restriction that prevent this from exististing, or a skilled programmer (which unfortunately I am not) might be able to overload some of the STL algorithms to make them work with `std::tuple` as well?

Comment: algorithms for tuple could be implemented but most of them doesn't make sense for tuple: what would return `std::find(std::make_tuple(5, "Hello"), 42)` ?

Comment: in that case it would result in a compilation error, as there is no overload for `operator==` that accepts `std::string` and `int`. But if your `std::tuple` were typed with `<double, int, char>` that would have compiled.

Comment: Even in that case, which return type and value do you get (success and failure case)?

Comment: Following how `std::find` currenlty works, it should return an iterator that points to the correct element, or to end if it does not find anything. But I see what is the problem you are raising here: since a tuple iterator has a different type of every element in the tuple, and it must be inferred by the compiler at compile-time, it is not possible to infer it has the comparison is not done until runtime. But there is another case: when the tuple is `constexpr`: in that case, it should be possible to use `std::find`. Is there such a thing as compile-time-evaluated algorithms in STL?

Comment: So it is not possible to write a `constexpr` function that can only work in a compile time context and, if it cannot be evaluated at compile time, gives compilation error?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, tuples are not containers per se. Of course, You can use them to store data but it is completely (or at least **can be**) completely heterogeneous. This leaves us with question why would You like to iterate over a heterogeneous data? In most situations there is no reason, I think. Mostly, when You iterate over something, You want to use similarities in iterated type to simplify Your work with familiar objects.

Of course there are corner cases with templates and so on and so forth when You would like to iterate over tuple. But I guess these are rare enough to spare the standard hell a lot of code and template magic to achieve what we would like. Anyway, there is already implementation of such iteration in [boost fusion](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/). Maybe it will become part of standard someday, as many other boost libraries before.

Comment: There are many reason why you might want to iterate over heterogeneous data. One that comes to my mind easily is serialization. Of course, the function you use has to have all the necessary overload to be able to be applied to every data type which is being stored in the tuple, but nevertheless, this is how generic programming works. So the question is: is it not possible under the current standard features to provide, for example, an `std::for_each` overload for `std::tuple`, or it is actually possible but nobody took the time to standardize it?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 As I pointed out, it is possible in C++ and even done in boost fusion.

Comment: I saw your link to boost fusion, and I still have some doubt about it: since it redefines every container to make them heterogeneous, I am not sure that their implementation of `for_each` can be considered a proper overload of `std::for_each`, meaning that I am not sure if it is able to work with a normal homogeneous container such as `std::vector`, `std::map` and so on. It looks more like a heterogeneous implementation for heterogeneous container only, like if it is not actually possible to provide the same function for both heterogeneous and homogeneous type of containers.